# Not showing any bootable options on grub

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.10

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and trying to install windows 7 instead, but when I hold shift on start-up to open the grub menu, there's no other bootable options. I'm trying to boot from a CD but it doesn't give me the option to install windows. I'm very new to linux and ubuntu, I would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

Insert your windows installation cd on the cd-drive.On startup,enter into the bios and change the boot option to CD drive.

Now your pc boots from the CD drive,install windows over Ubuntu.